# Preventing Apache from logging 403 errors

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, error-log

I want to prevent Apache 2.4 from logging 403 errors.

Conditional logging is described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html, but this refers to the access log.

In httpd.conf, I tried:

```
ErrorLogFormat "%!403[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M"
```

Nope. I tried several variations, but Apache still gives an error. Maybe, conditional logging is not possible in the error log?